# Android Animation Performance

Tags: android, android-animation, performance

If I use a gif image instead of an xml file (< animation-list>), would I save processing to display an animation?

I have to build an application where the battery consumption is critical. So I have to search multiple issues like this. 
Where can I find information related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Animated GIF images these are not fully supported on Android.

Here is a link to a discussion about them (both native and browser display)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

In my testing the most efficient (CPU and battery) animations are stored in XML because they can be compiled and avoid on-demand parsing or other processing that would be required for a GIF or frame animation with drawables.